# OpenCV vector to Mat but not element->row

Tags: opencv, vector, matrix

There is a very simple way to construct a Mat from a vector...just by doing:

```
vector<int> myVector;
Mat myMatFromVector(myVector,true); //the boolean is to define if you want to copy the data
```

The problem with this contructor is that each vector's element will be placed in each row of the Matrix. What I want is each element of my vector to be placed in each column of the matrix.

```
As is:
vector<int> = [1,2,3,4]
Matrix = [1;2;3;4]

I want:
vector<int> = [1,2,3,4]
Matrix = [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either specify the shape and type of the Matrix and pass the vector data

```
   // constructor for matrix headers pointing to user-allocated data
    Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
    Mat(Size _size, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
```

Or call reshape on the Mat to swap the number of row sand columns ( doesn't change any data)

```
    // creates alternative matrix header for the same data, with different
    // number of channels and/or different number of rows. see cvReshape.
    Mat reshape(int _cn, int _rows=0) const;
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but how do you correctly typecast `myVector` into the `void* _data` argument of the constructor?

Comment: Just (void*)myVector[0]

Comment: Thank you. Vectors are not _simply_ arrays right? It is incorrect to do `(void*)myVector`.

Comment: @a-jays elements of a vector are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory just like arrays. So the data starts at the address of the first element. A pointer to the vector object itself isn't necessarily a pointer to the data it contains

Answer (score 2):

The matrix formed by reflecting a matrix through its main diagonal (ie interchanging the rows and columns) is called the transpose. Using OpenCV, you can easily obtain the transpose of a matrix A as:

```
Mat A;
Mat A_transpose = A.t();
```

If A is [1; 2; 3; 4], A_transpose will be [1, 2, 3, 4] as required.

So, you could either create a transposed copy of your matrix after converting it from the vector, or you could create it easily when subsequently required in your calculations.

```
Mat A, B;
Mat answer = A.t() * B;
```